# Get list of GCS files in a bucket using Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to get the list of all/required files from a GCS bucket in a Dataflow pipeline?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `DoFn` that uses the GCS API to list the files in a bucket. Is there something more specific you are trying to doing?